# JavaScript keypresses giving weird responses

Tags: javascript, events, keycode, keyup

I've been taking input from the arrow keys for days now and it hasn't been giving me a problem. However, when I try to take input from the letter keys, they give strange and inconsistent responses.

When I print out the output of pressing down the keys to the console, I get inconsistent numbers. For example, when I press Q, I can get anything from 48-57 or so, and it seems to increment and loop around (the first time I press it, it's 48, or occasionally 81 [which is the correct keycode by my research]. The second time, it's 49 [but never 81 again], etc. until I get to 57-ish, at which point it goes to 48 again).

Annoyingly as well, I'm getting the same numbers with all of the letter keys. It's not just my site, either; the bottom of [this](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) site is giving me the same issues! I'm not sure if it's a local problem.

If it's relevant, I'm getting the keycode like this:

`window.addEventListener('keyup',function(event){console.log(event.keyCode);},false);`

Comment: I've mashed Q & W on that website for a minute, but the only 2 numbers that came up were 81 and 87... the problem might be local :P

Comment: In that event, do you have any idea how I can figure out what the hell is going on?

Comment: Have you tried using a different browser?

Comment: Just tried IE. IE is working fine. Chrome is not. Gonna try Firefox soon. Might just restart to see if that works, as well.

Comment: Use a different browser and/or computer to first diagnose if its a local environment issue. Pretty funny if you had a keylogger installed (I've heard some can cause issues like this).

Comment: So... The other website works in IE without fail. In Chrome and Firefox, it starts off saying that the button I'm pressing is Q, and then it says it's 0,1,2,3... in the textbox that you type into. In IE, the site I'm working on in particular isn't working for the same reason it's not working in Chrome or Firefox. I have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I've had much better luck going off the charCode.  I only use the keyCode if there's no charCode value.  Chrome should work just find then.  You can convert the charCode to a charString via String.fromCharCode(charCode).